# Removing excessive returns and newlines

Tags: javascript, bash

I'm sending some bash output to a web page, but it contains an excessive amount of \n, \r, and ^M characters. For example, a line may end with \r\n, and then the following line will contain ^M^M and no text. What would be the best way to remove these extra characters, while still having a newline after each line?

Currently having JS replace multiple newline and return characters with a single one, but that doesn't account for lines that have nothing but return characters. Also, I'm unsure of how JS actually sees characters like ^M and ^G. The output is collected via python subprocess and sent to an ajax function as an HttpResponse (using Django as the framework)

JavaScript:

```js
data = data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\r\n\r|\n\n|\r\r|\n\r)/g, '<br>');
```

Raw-text

```
Connection to node1 closed.^M^M
Connection to fsgvc11 closed.^M^M
Rebooting node7^M
^G^M^M
Broadcast message from root (pts/0) (Sat Sep 19 16:10:09 2015):^M^M
^M^M
```

How it looks in terminal

```
Connection to node1 closed.
Connection to fsgvc11 closed.
Rebooting node7

Broadcast message from root (pts/0) (Sat Sep 19 16:10:09 2015):
```

How it looks in browser:

```
Connection to node1 closed.

Connection to fsgvc11 closed.

Rebooting node7


Broadcast message from root (pts/0) (Sat Sep 19 16:10:09 2015):
```

Comment: What does your current JavaScript look like?

Comment: The bit to replace it uses a regex:  

`data = data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\r\n\r|\n\n|\r\r|\n\r)/g, '<br>');`

Comment: Ok, I added that to the question.

Comment: `.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,'<br>')`

Answer (score 1):

Is it bash or python? I didn't get it because you're talking about python but your tag says bash.

Maybe it simply helps you to be able to enter the ^M sign to replace it in a bash script like

```
echo $myvar | sed 's/^M//g'
```

You can insert it into i.e. vim by using ctrl+v ctrl+m.

Comment: Well its a bash script called from python. Like I said, I'm using Django as my web framework. ajax calls a python function that ends up calling a bash script, collecting the stdout using the subprocess module, and sends it back. As far as your suggestion, couldn't that result in a loss of newlines? In the example given, that would remove at ^M characters, so that would all end up being a single line, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Note that using `echo $myvar` will cause bash to remove all newline characters.   If you don't want that, put `$myvar` in double-quotes.

Comment: Depends on your way to deliver the content. ^M is only one sign of \n\r to other one still exists after removing ^M.

Answer (score 1):

vim (and some other editors) show carriage returns as "^M" but they are still carriage returns.

```
$ echo $'a\nb\r\nc\rd' >test
```

If you look at test via `vim test` you'll see

`a
b^M
c^Md`

If you look at it via anything that renders `\r`, you'll see

`$ cat test
a
b
d`

To fix this via bash:

```
$ cat test | tr '\r' '\n' > test2
```

View the file via vim `vim test2` and voila, all bad `^M`'s are gone.